# How to create a square grid in the PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to create a sudoku-like square grid in the PowerPoint, but I can't find a simple way to do it.

I can't precisely adjust the cell size with the table tool, and it is hard to align other graphs with the cells.

Is any plugin or some other softwares able to quickly create a square grid?

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about other versions of PowerPoint but you can do this out of the box in PowerPoint 2007.

Create your table, select all the cells, pick the **Layout** tab on the ribbon and cell your desired cell size there.

[image: PowerPoint screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't put other graphs (ex: a circle) into the table. I just tried to draw a lot of squares and align them together, which works better.

Comment: In PowerPoint 2010 this is done by using insert>>Table

Answer (score 4):

Tip: You can convert a table into perfectly aligned individual square shapes in 2010 by saving the table as a .emf, and re-inserting the picture. Use "Edit Picture" to have PowerPoint convert it to shapes. 
Use the selection pane to quickly remove unneeded elements (the conversion will create extra shapes for the borders of the cells etc, which you probably do not want)